# How can I (temporarily) restrict access to the system to a given user and/or group?

Tags: 2013, security, user-management

I wanted to check with you if by "disabling" an user I am removing his ability to log on to the system. I need to revoke access temporarily to different users (or groups) and wanted to know if there is anything I should consider before doing so.

Thanks,[image: Disabling an User]

Comment: Yes, disabling a user will stop them from logging in. You can enable them back later on.

Comment: How can we disable users using core service ? we have a around 1000 users.we have a requirement to disable users for a short time and enable it after some time.Could you please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Two things spring to mind (I'm sure there are more!):

1. You need to be careful that by disabling users that you do not 'block' items that are going through Workflow. This may be a problem if, for example, you disable all of the users in a particular group that are needed to approve content.
2. You may also need to keep in mind that although you have disabled a user, they may still have items in the publishing queue that we scheduled to publish at an earlier date.

Comment: Awesome! I am also aware of "checked-out" items by those users. Thanks